# How to interrupt and remove background function calls in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

the script only shows what is needed. Let me explain, **I am looking for the user to click on any button that does not execute the bound function if the user is dragging the mouse**, a solution would be to use `<ButtonPress>` and `<ButtonRelease>`, but the application is based on `OOP` and there are too many buttons ,** so it would also be ineffective to link each button to a callback**, **and another difficulty is that all widgets are linked to a link that allows the window to be moved**. *I was wondering if there is any link to link to all the buttons and turn them off when the mouse is pressed and turn them back on when they are released*. I can not think of anything else. If anyone could help me find a solution, I would be enormously grateful. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class Btn(Frame):
    def__init__(self, master, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(self, text='hellow', command=self.funtion)
        self.btn .pack()
        #posi...   
        #self.btn.bind('<ButtonPress>', callback)
        #self.btn.bind('<ButtonRelease>',callback)

    def funtion(self):
        print('hellow')

root = Tk()
frm = Btn(root, bg='green')
frm.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use ttk Buttons and using style.map. after defined the behaviour you would just need to add the style in the options and make sure its ttk. Since you used wildcard imports it could take some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind_all` on parent widget with `ButtonPress-1` and `ButtonRelease-1` as this code snippet demonstrates.

This updated answer limits `bind_all` affect to buttons that are within a specific container.

```py
parent = tk.Tk()
parent.title("Parent Widget")
frame = tk.Frame(parent)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

def press(ev):
    if ev.widget.master == frame:
        ev.widget["state"] = "disabled"

def release(ev):
    if ev.widget.master == frame:
        ev.widget["state"] = "normal"

for a in range(10):
    BUT = tk.Button(frame, text = "Press and Drag")
    BUT.grid(row = a, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

frame.bind_all("<B1-Motion>", press)
frame.bind_all("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)

label = tk.Frame(parent)
label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)
for a in range(10):
    BUT = tk.Button(label, text = "Press and Drag")
    BUT.grid(row = a, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think *bind_all* is the solution here. Think about it, bind_all will literally bind all widgets to that command and in addition it's always the same command.

Comment: My answer is a simple demonstration but your point is valid. I'll rewrite it to make the action more specific, for example limiting the response to objects in a specified container.